# Automatically `\protect` arguments sent to existing command

Tags: robust-commands, protected-macro, fragile

Say you are using [`titlecaps`](https://ctan.org/pkg/titlecaps) and you have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlecaps}

\begin{document}
  \def\makemytitle#1{{\Large \titlecap{#1}}}
  \makemytitle{The lazy fox jumps over \protect\LaTeX}
\end{document}
```

Now if you remove the `\protect` macro in the above it fails. Presumably because the `\LaTeX`-command wouldn't be able to be title-cased, which makes sense.

My question is this: are there any way, in the definition of `\makemytitle`, to make all macros sent as argument to `\makemytitle` are automatically `\protect`ed?

That is - the above code should run without using `\protect` in the `\makemytitle`-call, but `\protect` may be used in the *definition* of `\makemytitle`.

Thanks :)

Comment: Use `\DeclareRobustCommand` for the definition of the parameter macro?

Comment: `\LaTeX` is declared as robust so should never need `\protect`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle here it's needed though.

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman so I see, looks like a bug in `\titlecap` let me see....

Comment: hmm I have to be careful where I look, need to make sure the blame is not apportioned here: `%% THE FOLLOWING THREE LINES ARE FROM DAVID CARLISLE`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hahaahaha! Brilliant if it’s your fault! As I’ve said before; your name pops up everywhere!